# orderBy multiple fields in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

How to sort by using multiple fields at same time in angular? fist by group and then by sub-group
for Example

```
$scope.divisions = [{'group':1,'sub':1}, {'group':2,'sub':10}, {'group':1,'sub':2},{'group':1,'sub':20},{'group':2,'sub':1},
    {'group':2,'sub':11}];
```

I wanted to display this as

#### group : Sub-group

1 - 1

1 - 2

1 - 20

2 - 1

2 - 10

2 - 11

```
<select ng-model="divs" ng-options="(d.group+' - '+d.sub) for d in divisions | orderBy:'group' | orderBy:'sub'" />
```

Answer (score 683, accepted):

Please see this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/Hp4W7/32/

```
<div ng-repeat="division in divisions | orderBy:['group','sub']">{{division.group}}-{{division.sub}}</div>
```

Comment: `orderBy:['-group','sub']` for sorting by `group` in reverse order.

Comment: Does the group field have priority for being first in the orderBy List?

Comment: @luchosrock, yes it does, as expected. Playing with the provided jsfiddle easily confirms sort priority is from left to right for the provided sort fields.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to give priority to one of the fields?  For example in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abyrne85/apfw1Lm5/2/) I would like the items with a value for 'sub' to appear at the top of the list, then the rest of the values can be arranged by group.

Comment: Note that the optional reverseOrder parameter does not support an array like the expression param does, but you can omit it and instead provide sort order on each array item so that they are reversed (or not) separately. Example: orderBy: ['group', '-sub'] will sort by group in normal fashion, then by sub in reverse order. It is possible to get some complex combinations this way.

Comment: We simulated priority in our shop by giving the array items a boolean property, then using that as the first option. Example:    orderBy: ['-featured', 'title'], which caused the featured true items to be at the top (alphabetically), then the rest of the items listed alphabetically.

Comment: I have trouble sorting by two properties. When I sortby name and then age, it does not sort by age. Here is my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/gqZaKbb7TwnvGGewydPv?p=preview

Comment: If you want to sort by multiple fields chosen from a select directive, be sure to convert the value from a string to an array.  
Example: for selected option <select ng-model="sortoption"><option value="-sub,group">..., use orderby: sortoption.split(",")

Answer (score 50):

If you wants to sort on mulitple fields inside controller use this

```
$filter('orderBy')($scope.property_list, ['firstProp', 'secondProp']);
```

See also https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Answer (score 21):

```
<select ng-model="divs" ng-options="(d.group+' - '+d.sub) for d in divisions | orderBy:['group','sub']" />
```

User array instead of multiple orderBY

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 ways of doing AngularJs filters, one in the HTML using {{}} and one in actual JS files...

You can solve you problem by using :

```
{{ Expression | orderBy : expression : reverse}}
```

if you use it in the HTML or use something like:

```
$filter('orderBy')(yourArray, yourExpression, reverse)
```

The reverse is optional at the end, it accepts a boolean and if it's true, it will reverse the Array for you, very handy way to reverse your Array...

Comment: Also here to have a look: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Answer (score 7):

Sorting can be done by using 'orderBy' filter in angular.

Two ways:
   1. From view
   2. From controller

1. From view

Syntax:

```
{{array | orderBy : expression : reverse}}
```

For example:

```
 <div ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy : ['name', 'age'] : true">{{user.name}}</div>
```

2. From controller

Syntax:

```
$filter.orderBy(array, expression, reverse);
```

For example:

```
$scope.filteredArray = $filter.orderBy($scope.users, ['name', 'age'], true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this handy piece to sort by multiple columns / properties of an object. With each successive column click, the code stores the last column clicked and adds it to a growing list of clicked column string names, placing them in an array called sortArray. The built-in Angular "orderBy" filter simply reads the sortArray list and orders the columns by the order of column names stored there. So the last clicked column name becomes the primary ordered filter, the previous one clicked the next in precedence, etc. The reverse order affects all columns order at once and toggles ascending/descending for the complete array list set:

```
<script>
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.sortArray = ['name'];
        $scope.sortReverse1 = false;
        $scope.searchProperty1 = '';
        $scope.addSort = function (x) {
            if ($scope.sortArray.indexOf(x) === -1) {
                $scope.sortArray.splice(0,0,x);//add to front
            }
            else {
                $scope.sortArray.splice($scope.sortArray.indexOf(x), 1, x);//remove
                $scope.sortArray.splice(0, 0, x);//add to front again
            }
        };
        $scope.sushi = [
        { name: 'Cali Roll', fish: 'Crab', tastiness: 2 },
        { name: 'Philly', fish: 'Tuna', tastiness: 2 },
        { name: 'Tiger', fish: 'Eel', tastiness: 7 },
        { name: 'Rainbow', fish: 'Variety', tastiness: 6 },
        { name: 'Salmon', fish: 'Misc', tastiness: 2 }
        ];
    });
</script>
<table style="border: 2px solid #000;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="addSort('name');sortReverse1=!sortReverse1">NAME<span ng-show="sortReverse1==false">&#9660;</span><span ng-show="sortReverse1==true">&#9650;</span></a></td>
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="addSort('fish');sortReverse1=!sortReverse1">FISH<span ng-show="sortReverse1==false">&#9660;</span><span ng-show="sortReverse1==true">&#9650;</span></a></td>
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="addSort('tastiness');sortReverse1=!sortReverse1">TASTINESS<span ng-show="sortReverse1==false">&#9660;</span><span ng-show="sortReverse1==true">&#9650;</span></a></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="s in sushi | orderBy:sortArray:sortReverse1 | filter:searchProperty1">
        <td>{{ s.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ s.fish }}</td>
        <td>{{ s.tastiness }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Created Pipe for sorting. Accepts both string and array of strings, sorting by multiple values. Works for Angular (not AngularJS). Supports both sort for string and numbers.

```js
@Pipe({name: 'orderBy'})
export class OrderBy implements PipeTransform {
    transform(array: any[], filter: any): any[] {
        if(typeof filter === 'string') {
            return this.sortAray(array, filter)
        } else {
            for (var i = filter.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
                array = this.sortAray(array, filter[i]);
            }

            return array;
        }
    }

    private sortAray(array, field) {
        return array.sort((a, b) => {
            if(typeof a[field] !== 'string') {
                a[field] !== b[field] ? a[field] < b[field] ? -1 : 1 : 0
            } else {
                a[field].toLowerCase() !== b[field].toLowerCase() ? a[field].toLowerCase() < b[field].toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1 : 0
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: Actually in my opinion no one currently has answered to actual question, cause it was for Angular, not AngularJS. My solution works starting from Angular 2. Tested on Angular 7.2.15

Comment: You should consider a) when was this question asked, and b) when was Angular 2 first announced.

Comment: @andris Do you have a working end to end code example hosted somewhere ?

Comment: Sorry, but no :(

Answer (score -8):

Make sure that the sorting is not to complicated for the end user. I always thought sorting on group and sub group is a little bit complicated to understand. If its a technical end user it might be OK.

Comment: This is not even a relevant "comment". For sure not an answer to the question

Comment: Is it so wrong to ask yourself if the current approach is the best when your doing GUI development? The end user experience feels relevant to me

Comment: There are plenty of scenarios where sorting by multiple properties makes it easier for the user to understand the organization. You're essentially grouping things into categories.