# AngularJS: Is the an orderByOrderBy like filterFilter?

Tags: angularjs

I have a table in which I am using the doSort() example that is in most AngularJS tutorials to sort the data by column. However, since I am using up the orderBy with doSort(), I can't figure out how to do the default sort.

I tried to stack the orderBy (like you can with filter) but the default is not working.

here's my table but the orderBy: dueDate is being ignored --

```
<table id="tblProjects" class="tblLanding" ng-hide="projectManagerClose">
        <tr class="landing_header_row">
          <th style="width:7%;" data-ng-click="doProjSort('Priority')">Priority</th>
          <th style="width:3%;" data-ng-click="doProjSort('Task_Id')">ID</th>
          <th style="width:17%;" data-ng-click="doProjSort('Description')">Description</th>
          <th style="width:10%;" data-ng-click="doProjSort('Status')">Status</th>
          <th style="width:15%;" data-ng-click="doProjSort('Division')">Division</th>
          <th style="width:12%;" data-ng-click="doProjSort('Requestor')">Requestor</th>
          <th style="width:12%;" data-ng-click="doProjSort('ProjMan')">Project Manager</th>
          <th style="width:12%;" data-ng-click="doProjSort('AssignedTo')">Assigned To</th>
          <th style="width:12%;" data-ng-click="doProjSort('DueDate')">Due Date</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="landing_data_row" data-ng-repeat="project in open_projects | 
                filter: pmProjectsFilter | filter: statusFilter | 
                orderBy: DueDate | orderBy:sortProjBy:reverse">
            <td><div class='sprite indic-{{project.Priority}} centered'></div></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">{{project.Task_Id}}</td>
            <td><a href="#">{{project.Description}}</a></td>
            <td>{{project.Status}}</td>
            <td>{{project.Division}}</td>
            <td>{{project.Requestor}}</td>
            <td>{{project.ProjMan}}</td>
            <td>{{project.AssignedTo}}</td>
            <td>{{project.DueDate | date : 'MMM dd, yyyy'}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: See the following question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037524/orderby-multiple-fields-in-angular]

Comment: the array works fine with two of the fields but hides all records when I use | orderBy: 'DueDate', 'sortProjBy:reverse' |

Comment: I would consider having a sortString type "model" that your sort function (doProjSort) operates on. Then use the sortString as the param for orderBy. The string should be like "+column1, -column2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing single quotes around `'DueDate'`.  This is necessary because it is a literal string, not a variable like `sortProjBy`.

```
    <tr class="landing_data_row" data-ng-repeat="project in open_projects | 
            orderBy:'DueDate' | orderBy:sortProjBy:reverse">
```

This actually does sort the data initially by DueDate.  Then, when a value is assigned to `sortProjBy`, the second `orderBy` will override the first `orderBy`.  Here is a plunker demonstrating this behavior:   http://plnkr.co/edit/GNN7m90e3PYfTmxoNdbn?p=preview

If you want to achieve sorting on multiple columns (always sorting by DueDate, and then by the clicked column), use the [array syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037524/orderby-multiple-fields-in-angular):

```
    <tr class="landing_data_row" data-ng-repeat="project in open_projects | 
            orderBy:['DueDate',sortProjBy]">
```

Here is demo of the array syntax: http://plnkr.co/edit/FQxPNmwVNMd4lmn9mPSZ?p=preview