# order by of angularjs for sorting based on three different parameters

Tags: angularjs, sql-order-by

I am using order by of Angular for sorting but I want to sort data based on three different fields, i.e `success`, `in-progress` and `failed`, without using any constant and variable directly from in-built function. Is there any way?

Comment: as I understand it you are looking for this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037524/orderby-multiple-fields-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

you can pass array of fields to orderBy

```
<div ng-repeat="row in list | orderBy:['param1','param2']">
....
</div>
```

**EDIT**

to do it in javascript

```
 $scope.sortedList = $filter('orderBy')(list,['param1', 'param2']);
```

**EDIT**

in smart table

```
   function customSortAlgorithm(arrayRef, sortPredicate, reverse) {
   //do some stuff
    return sortedArray;
   }
scope.globalConfig = {
    sortAlgorithm: customSortAlgorithm
};
```

Comment: hiii harish, actually i am using forEach to load the whole data something can be done with the help of sortPredicate of angular ?????in smart-table content i need this sorting.

Comment: so you want to sort data in javascript and not in html??

Comment: yes in smart table whole directive is loading and on particular column i want to perform this search.

Comment: hello,my code is::::    isSortable : true,
    sortPredicate: function(dataRow){
     if(dataRow.completedTableauConversionStatus === 3)
      return -1;
     else if(dataRow.completedTableauConversionStatus === 2)
      return  1;
     else if(dataRow.completedTableauConversionStatus === 4)
      return  2;
   }                                               ----------------------------------------------------------------        here i am using status code but i can not constants like 1,2 3 so is there any other statement that i can return .

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can call a function to sort your data as you want.

you can call following custom 'orderBy'

```
        $scope.sort = function(column,reverse) {
        $scope.persons = $filter('orderBy')($scope.persons,column,reverse);
    };
```

'$scope.persons' - is your collection of data you need to order 
'column' - name of the column you want to sort data
'reverse'- bool value to reverse the order

and you can call this 'sort' function from your View(HTML) as below.

```
data-ng-click="sort('name',nameReverse)"
```

Comment: i want to perform sorting on a particular column of smart table.

Comment: smart table also has data source. what you want to do is pass your data source to above function. Or you can pass smart table 'rowCollection' to the above function. and you can call the function when header click.