# Angular orderBy multiple fields with priority given to one field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Following on from a previous question on this topic ([orderBy multiple fields in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037524/orderby-multiple-fields-in-angular)), I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve [this](http://jsfiddle.net/abyrne85/apfw1Lm5/3/).   Essentially, I want to orderBy multiple fields, but give priority to one of the fields if their value isn't null.

I'm using orderBy like so:

```
orderBy:['-sub','group']
```

From what I understand, the first item in the list of fields is given priority, but they are appearing at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Then you should do something like this `orderBy:['!-sub','group']"`

**Markup**

```
<div class="test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="division in divisions | orderBy:['!-sub','group']">
       {{division.group}}-{{division.sub}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/apfw1Lm5/5/)

Comment: This works nicely. Thank you very much.  Out of interest, where did you find this?  There is no mention in the docs about '!'.

Comment: @abyrne85 I was playing with it..It got worked..Really that was amazing.. :)