# Vue: orderBy multiple fields

Tags: vue.js

I would like to use the VueJS orderBy filter with multiple fields. I've tried:

[orderBy multiple fields in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037524/orderby-multiple-fields-in-angular) (a similar approach)

and

```
| orderBy 'ignored' true | orderBy 'name' 1 | ...
```

but neither solution works.

Is it possible to use the orderBy filter with multiple fields and if so, how? If not, can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Hello, you'll be able to orderBy multiple fields in vue@1.0.21 or in vue@1.1.0. The PR implementing this was merged today: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/2562

The syntax will be : `contacts | orderBy ['name', 'surname', 'age'] reverse`

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would avoid the builtin orderBy filter. Other options:

1. Create a `computed` that does this for you.
2. Create a `watch` that automatically performs the sort and stores it into a new attribute (e.g. "something_sorted") whenever the array of items change.
3. Create your own custom filter which performs a multicolumn sort. (http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-filter.html)

Answer (score 0):

My script is:

```
$scope.myarray = $filter('orderBy')(array, ['field1','field2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to concatenate the terms like so;

`<element v-for="item in array | orderBy 'ignored+name'">`

`ignored` will filter alphabetically so I would suggest add a bang before ignored to flip the order.

Answer (score 0):

i did it in v1 by using syntax below as @Posva said in comment..
`contacts | orderBy ['name', 'surname', 'age'] reverse`