# order by combination of two fields in angular

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

I know that it is possible to sort a table in angular with two column separately, i.e. first sort by name then sort by family.

https://plnkr.co/edit/bJIIlmGLyGWsxD5AQti0

```
var friends = [
  {name: 'a',   family: 'z',  age: 10},
  {name: 'z',   family: 'b',  age: 19},
  {name: 'c',   family: 'z',  age: 21},
  {name: 'z',   family: 'd',  age: 35},
  {name: 'z',  family: 'e',  age: 29}
];

$scope.propertyName = 'age';
$scope.reverse = true;
$scope.friends = orderBy(friends, $scope.propertyName, $scope.reverse);

$scope.sortBy = function(propertyName) {
  $scope.reverse = (propertyName !== null && $scope.propertyName === propertyName)
      ? !$scope.reverse : false;
  $scope.propertyName = propertyName;
  $scope.friends = orderBy(friends, ['name','family'], $scope.reverse);
};
}]);
})(window.angular);
```

I wonder if it is possible to sort them by combining the two fields, e.g order by "name" and "family" alphabetically, so it is appearing as "a,b,c,d,e"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [orderBy multiple fields in Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037524/orderby-multiple-fields-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="student in students | orderBy:['name','family']">
    {{student.name}}-{{student.family}}
</div>
```

Comment: in this case, it is ordering by name and then family, it is not score them base on the combination of these two fields. so I like to achieve "a b c d e f " not "a c b d"

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass an `Array` to angular `orderBy` filter, this way:

```
ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:['name', 'family']"
```

**UPDATE**: after question change by OP, I ask you to better state the requested ordering function, since it is not very clear (to me) from the question...

Comment: i am looking to score the order by combining two fields, so it will appear as below {name: 'a',   family: 'z',  age: 10},
  {name: 'z',   family: 'b',  age: 19},
  {name: 'c',   family: 'z',  age: 21},
  {name: 'z',   family: 'd',  age: 35},
  {name: 'z',  family: 'e',  age: 29}

Comment: I was not asking for an example, but for a definition... :-)