# Filtering and sorting a JSON array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

```
records = [
        {
            name: "Alpha",
            set: 5,
            weight: 185
        },      
        {
            name: "Alpha",
            set: 5,
            weight: 350
        },        
        {
            name: "Bravo",
            set: 5,
            weight: 185
        },        
        {
            name: "Charlie",
            set: 5,
            weight: 185
        },         
        {
            name: "Delta",
            set: 5,
            weight: 185
        }
]
```

I have a JSON array of multiple records and I need to filter these records by name and weight.  So for example, since there are two "Alpha" records, I need to only pull in the one with the highest weight (which would be the second record).  I have no idea how to filter and rebuild this array with only the desired results.

I need to keep the original array intact as I'll be displaying ALL in a table, but I need to build a secondary array with only the objects with the greatest value, by name.

Comment: Refer this similar Question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17037756/6449750

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you start using lodash and dont spend time to create your own functions. For example, to sort your array by name you should write the following code:

```
    var records = [
        {
            name: "Alpha",
            set: 5,
            weight: 185
        },      
        {
            name: "Alpha",
            set: 5,
            weight: 350
        },        
        {
            name: "Bravo",
            set: 5,
            weight: 185
        },        
        {
            name: "Charlie",
            set: 5,
            weight: 185
        },         
        {
            name: "Delta",
            set: 5,
            weight: 185
        }
];
var sorted = _.sortBy(records, ['name']);
```

And second case, to filter by name and weight

```
var filtered = _.filter(records, [ 'name': 'Alpha', 'weight': 350 ]);
```

Comment: Does this also filter out multiple of the same type? As this is something OP wants

Comment: And code will look like _.filter(records, [name:"Alpha", weight: 350]

Comment: It should be included in the answer, as of now your solution only solves the sorting.

Comment: Updated the solution

Answer (score 4):

You can use lodash 4+ for this.

***var sortedArray = _.orderBy(records, ['weight'], ['desc']);***

This will sort the array by weight.
Then ,
***_.uniqBy(sortedArray,'name')***

This will return the final array.

```js
var records = [
        {
            name: "Alpha",
            set: 5,
            weight: 185
        },      
        {
            name: "Alpha",
            set: 5,
            weight: 350
        },        
        {
            name: "Bravo",
            set: 5,
            weight: 185
        },        
        {
            name: "Charlie",
            set: 5,
            weight: 185
        },         
        {
            name: "Delta",
            set: 5,
            weight: 185
        }
]

var sortedArray = _.orderBy(records, ['weight'], ['desc'])

_.uniqBy(sortedArray,'name')
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend a functional programming approach:

```
var newRecords = records
    .filter(function(record) { 
        return records.find(function(innerRecord) {
            return innerRecord.name === record.name && innerRecord.weight > record.weight; }) === undefined;
     });
```

In this example, you return only records where you cannot find a record sharing the same name but with a larger weight. Also, your newly re-built array is stored in `newRecords`, leaving your original array intact.

Answer (score 2):

This first sorts the items in name order and weight order and then filter out all but the first of each item.

```js
var records = [{
    name: "Alpha",
    set: 5,
    weight: 185
  },
  {
    name: "Alpha",
    set: 5,
    weight: 350
  },
  {
    name: "Bravo",
    set: 5,
    weight: 185
  },
  {
    name: "Charlie",
    set: 5,
    weight: 185
  },
  {
    name: "Charlie",
    set: 5,
    weight: 200
  },
  {
    name: "Delta",
    set: 5,
    weight: 185
  }
]

console.log(
  records.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.name === b.name) {
      return a.weight >= b.weight ? -1 : 1
    }
    return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1
  })
  .filter((rec, i, arr) => {
    if (i === 0) return true
    return rec.name !== arr[i - 1].name
  })
)
```